# CSRF Tokens with separate API and Web Server

Tags: csrf, csrf-token

I am learning about CSRF Tokens and how they help secure your web application. I understand the basics of it, but I am confused as to how it works in practice when the web server and api are separate. In practice how is the token generated, added to the HTML and known by the API?

For example, if I host my web app on something like Nginx or S3 and serve APIs via Spring Boot, how does the HTML with the embedded token get generated and passed to the client? Would the Sprint Boot API need to generate the token and HTML and return that to the client? Is there a different flow that am I missing? If this is the case, what is the point of it being embedded in HTML at all?

All of the documentation I have read assumes you are using something like MVC or skips over this entirely.

Comment: APIs typically don't need to be aware of a CSRF token, unless you're doing something unusual. In places where you use an `Authorization` header, it's unlikely need this.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection is only necessary for requests made by a client (for example, a browser) that silently adds credentials for the current user, by sending a session cookie, resending username and password that were previously typed in ("Basic Authentication") or by including a client certificate. This is because users may be tricked into making unwanted such requests by visiting a malicious web page, and these unwanted requests are then made with their credentials, that is, *on their behalf*.

For requests made by your web server to an API endpoint, this does not apply, therefore the API endpoint need not offer CSRF protection. A web server cannot be tricked into making unwanted requests.

Or can it? Imagine that the web server offers a "proxy" endpoint that converts incoming requests into requests to the API endpoint, and that sends the API response back to the client:

```
Client --request--> web server --converted request--> API endpoint
Client <--converted response-- web server <--response-- API endpoint
```

Further imagine that, as part of the request conversion, credentials from the client are forwarded to the API. For example, a session cookie coming from the browser is converted into an `Authorization: Bearer <jwt>` header that is sent to the API endpoint. Then an unwanted request to the web server endpoint with credentials effectively becomes a request to the API, and a new CSRF vulnerability has appeared: this time on the web server.

The web server must then protect its own "proxy" endpoint against CSRF by issuing and validating a CSRF token.