# Is sending a cross-origin request from a browser and from a server any different?

Tags: node.js, cors

I have started reading about CORS and wanted to understand how it works, SOP states that by
default cross-origin requests are rejected by the server.
So I have created two servers on localhost, one for port 8081, another one for 8082.
The 8082 server looks like so:

```
const app = express();
//const cors = require('cors');
//app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }))

app.listen(8082, function () {
    console.log('server running on 8082')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log({ host: req.headers.host })
    console.log({ origin: req.headers.origin })
    return res.json('good');
});
```

the 8081 looks like so:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('server running on 8081')
})

app.get('/request', (req, res) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8082/').then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)

    return res.end();
});
```

Basically I just have the endpoint **/request** that tries to access the first server, aditionally
besides the **/request** endpoint I have an index.html file which I serve, which is located at public directory and looks like so:

```
<script>
  function t() {
     fetch('http://localhost:8082/').then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)
  }
</script>
<button onclick="t()"></button>
```

It does absolutely the same as the **/request** endpoint, so what I do not understand , is why when I click the button and the request gets sent to the first server I receive a CORS error,
but when I trigger the endpoint **/request** I receive a response without any CORS error displayed? Can someone explain this please?

Comment: The origin of a web page is the scheme + domain + port of the address in the address bar. In your case, this is `http://localhost:8081` . Any requests made by the browser that are not to this origin are considered to be cross-origin. Servers, on the other hand, are not constrained by cross-origin rules and can fetch data from anywhere they want, so you can use the server to proxy data from another origin, making it appear as if it comes from the same origin as the webpage. This side-steps CORS because the browser is merely fetching its data from the same origin.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation, I just started to learn about backend security and couldnt get my head around it. So as I understand it since servers are not constrained by cross-origin rules this means that if we would imagine a bank.com website, and a bankuser that would have a cookie in his browser that would automatically login him when he visits the bank.com, if I would make a fake website with the endpoint that sends a simple get request to the bank.com  and the user would navigate to this endpoint he would get logged even if bank.com has its cors enabled.

Comment: @spender The only thing I do not understand, if CORS can be bypassed by servers, why does it matter that CORS can not be bypassed by browsers, I mean I understand that it provides 'some' security, but if it is not a difinitive security mechanism, why does it exist in a first place?

Comment: CORS is not a defence. On the contrary, CORS's purpose is to _relax_ the Same-Origin Policy (SOP). Not all user agents implement the SOP; browsers do, but the likes of Postman and curl do not. The SOP is a set of restrictions meant to guard browser users from attacks mounted from one malicious Web origin and targeting another Web origin.

Comment: See the sections of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) with the headings "About the Same Origin Policy" and "Why the Same Origin Policy applies to JavaScript in a web page but little else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if CORS can be bypassed by servers, why does it matter that CORS can not be bypassed by browsers

This statement contrasts browsers and servers in a false way.

The same-origin policy is a behavior that a user agent making HTTP requests implements in order to protect the *user*. And CORS is a protocol for limited exceptions to this policy. Users are in control of their user agent, and they can forgo that protection (by starting their browser with a command line option like `--disable-web-security`), but they are then responsible for the consequences.

In other words: Users *can* manipulate their browsers so that the same-origin-policy is bypassed, and they can manipulate their servers as they see fit. In both cases, the *user* is responsible

- for the command line options they use with their browsers or
- for the way they program their servers or for the libraries they use for making HTTP requests.

### Why is there no same-origin policy/CORS on servers?

Two vulnerabilies that the same-origin policy is meant to protect users against are:

- Users can be tricked into making unwanted requests with their *browsers*, for example, by clicking a link or loading a malicious image in a web mail reader.
- When the browser makes a request, browser standards dictate that it silently inserts credentials that it knows of (see [CSRF Tokens with separate API and Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844997/csrf-tokens-with-separate-api-and-web-server)). This leads to an authenticated request being made (although possibly unwanted by the user).

The same-origin policy and CORS rely on the concept of the *origin* in the browser's address bar. This concept is not applicable to *servers*, which have no address bar. There is therefore no such thing as a "cross-origin request from a server". Also, it would be much harder to trick users into making unwanted requests with a server on their computer. Or it would require much more gullible users who download and run untrusted programs.

**To summarize:** In order to protect themselves, users are advised not to disable the same-origin policy on their browsers and not to run servers on their computer that make arbitrary requests. But since *the user is always in control of the HTTP client* (whether that is a browser or a server), users cannot be prevented from ignoring this advice.

Comment: _CORS is a code of behavior that a client making HTTP requests voluntarily adopts in order to protect the user._ What? That's not right... I think that, in many places of your response, you mean "SOP" rather than "CORS".

Comment: Not really  See the update in my comment above.

Comment: Much better. Sorry for being punctilious, but I feel that developers who miss this distinction sometimes unduly activate CORS, thinking it will somehow make their users safer. Better not propagate the confusion in SO answers :)

Comment: One last thing: _The same-origin policy is a code of behavior that a client making HTTP requests adopts in order to protect the user._ The SOP is not something the client chooses. Rather, it's implemented by the browser, period. And CORS allows the server to relax some of it for select clients.

Comment: By client I mean the program (browser, native app) that makes HTTP requests. CORS allows relaxing the SOP for select _origins_ (if the client co-operates with the SOP in the first place).

Comment: _User agent_ (the browser, in this case) is a more accurate term, and shouldn't be conflated with the concept of _client_.

Comment: @jub0bs: When a server (Node.js program, say) acts as an HTTP client, would you also call that a user agent?

Comment: Hmmm.... I guess not. But at least for browsers, distinguishing user agent (the browser itself) from client (some JS code sending requests from some Web origin) is useful.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, thanks for your reply, you are saying that SOP/CORS Policy is a browser thing, however if you would look at my example above I do exactly this. I send a link to a user which is test.com/request, the /request endpoint sends a request to the bank.com from my server. When user opens this link and the request is sent, there will not be any origin attached, therefore I will bypass the SOP. And if we would imagine that the user has some auth cookies for bank.com, those would be sent automatically therefore logging in the user.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen How would the user even know in advance before sending this request that it would be a request with the origin that will be atached or a one where the origin will not be atached, if he can not tell a difference between sending a browser/client request or a server request, because in both cases he doesnt know how the 'request sending' is implemented. In this case this is a simple login, but i may initiate a post or delete action the same way basically on his behalf if I have his cookies and can send any request to bank.com. Sorry if I do not get something.

Comment: The same-origin policy alone does not protect against all possible attacks. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412651/csrf-tokens-vs-session-cookies), [tag:samesite] and [tag:csrf].